# Execution in the datetime.timedelta function column

Tags: python, pandas

I heve DataFrame:

```
Id;TnbId;Date_Start;Days
468;18;2023-08-26;8
101;15;2023-08-11;1
97;18;2023-08-01;18
1618;18;2023-08-07;12
96;15;2023-08-04;1
..;..;...-..-..;..
```

What I want is:

```
Id;TnbId;Date_Start;Days
468;18;2023-08-26;8
468;18;2023-08-27;8
468;18;2023-08-28;8
468;18;2023-08-29;8
468;18;2023-08-30;8
468;18;2023-08-31;8
468;18;2023-09-01;8
101;15;2023-08-11;1
...;..;....-..-..
```

So in the "Date_start" column you need to fix something like this:

```
for i in range(1,Days):
    dt_result = DateStart + datetime.timedelta(days=i)
```

How can I do this on the entire frame?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [`repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) the rows, then increment the Date with [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html)+[`pandas.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
# ensure datetime
df['Date_Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Start'])

out = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Days'])]
out['Date_Start'] += pd.to_timedelta(out.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), unit='D')
```

Output:

```
     Id  TnbId Date_Start  Days
0   468     18 2023-08-26     8
0   468     18 2023-08-27     8
0   468     18 2023-08-28     8
0   468     18 2023-08-29     8
0   468     18 2023-08-30     8
0   468     18 2023-08-31     8
0   468     18 2023-09-01     8
0   468     18 2023-09-02     8
1   101     15 2023-08-11     1
2    97     18 2023-08-01    18
2    97     18 2023-08-02    18
2    97     18 2023-08-03    18
2    97     18 2023-08-04    18
2    97     18 2023-08-05    18
2    97     18 2023-08-06    18
2    97     18 2023-08-07    18
2    97     18 2023-08-08    18
2    97     18 2023-08-09    18
2    97     18 2023-08-10    18
2    97     18 2023-08-11    18
2    97     18 2023-08-12    18
2    97     18 2023-08-13    18
2    97     18 2023-08-14    18
2    97     18 2023-08-15    18
2    97     18 2023-08-16    18
2    97     18 2023-08-17    18
2    97     18 2023-08-18    18
3  1618     18 2023-08-07    12
3  1618     18 2023-08-08    12
3  1618     18 2023-08-09    12
3  1618     18 2023-08-10    12
3  1618     18 2023-08-11    12
3  1618     18 2023-08-12    12
3  1618     18 2023-08-13    12
3  1618     18 2023-08-14    12
3  1618     18 2023-08-15    12
3  1618     18 2023-08-16    12
3  1618     18 2023-08-17    12
3  1618     18 2023-08-18    12
4    96     15 2023-08-04     1
```

Comment: Everything works correctly. Thanks for fast help